Can pilots identify tail strike from the cockpit?
Is there any system, on board, that can warn pilots that a tail strike happened?

Other than, presumably, a palpable bang that shakes the whole plane?

Related: What is the purpose of the Dash 8’s “TOUCHED RUNWAY” warning light?

@DarthPseudonym There's also value in detecting a tailstrike has not occurred. More than one turnback has happened because shifting luggage caused a good thump during rotation.

@DarthPseudonym Depends. Sometimes a tail strike cannot even be felt in the cockpit.

Large aircraft have a tail contact sensor. On the A350, this sensor contains two independent electric loops which are broken when the contact occurs. This condition is reported to the crew using the MASTER CAUT (master caution) lights, an ECAM message and a chime as explained in this AAIB Bulletin:

When a tailstrike does occur, the two wires in the sensor are damaged and become open circuit from their normally grounded (GND) state. The change of signal state is detected by the Common Remote Data Concentrators which change the format of the data and transmits it to the Flight Warning System (FWS) via the Avionics Full Duplex
Switched Ethernet (AFDX).


The FWS shows a warning on the ECAM Warning Display providing the aircraft is in the appropriate flight phase, landing or taking off.


A single chime is also produced from the flight deck loudspeakers. On the cockpit glare shield and panels 411VU and 412VU, MASTER CAUT push buttons are also illuminated (Figure 8).


Other than an ECAM message, the system warnings are inhibited when TOGA is selected during landing.

A similar system exists on Boeing 787 (Dreamliner, see AAIB report):

Tail contact sensor on a Boeing 787. Source.
It seems older large aircraft, like Airbus A320 or Boeing 737, had sensors unable to trigger an alert. A light tail contact would be felt only by flight attendants at the rear of the cabin.
Remarks:

The flight control computers are assumed to prevent the contact to occur in the first place, by monitoring the pitch attitude, however for some reason, like after a bounce at landing, heavy cargo sliding in the rear bay, or wind gust, the aircraft may over-rotate without crew action and too fast for the protection to work.

A tail contact occurs within periods of sterile cockpit, FA must anyway report the contact without delay to the pilots. A tail contact affects first a non-pressurized area of the aircraft, but the pressure vessel may have been damaged too, preventing a safe pressurization, and a fire can also occur in the non-pressurized tail cone where the APU is usually located. A landing is required as soon as possible, and a limited altitude must be maintained.


See also:

 Why are so many tail-strike incidents not verified until later inspection?

 How do manufacturers engineer their aircraft to deal with tail strikes?

 What is the purpose of the Dash 8’s “TOUCHED RUNWAY” warning light? (identified earlier by Bianfable)

Airbus Safety First: A320 Tail strike at Take-Off?


